# Is there a way to add customer email in the wishlist share email template

Tags: php, magento2

I want to add a customer email in the email template. However, I am unable to add it. All I can see in template variable is

[image]

I have also tried to add `{{ var customer.email }}` in the email template. though no luck. How can I add a customer's email or any other customer's related information to the email template?

Comment: Which email template you need to add customer email?

Comment: @KamleshSolanki I have created my custom template from Marketing -> Email Templates

Comment: So you need to create custom variable like customer name for your custom module

Comment: yes @KamleshSolanki